# Is accessing carelessly not protected data of any service unlawfull?

Tags: legal, protection

The following scenario: I just visited the webpage of an phisshing company of an german service which is here in germany acting at least not unlawfull, but just trying to get money for not even giving something usefull.

After surfing a bit I filled a formular which just gave me a php created response with a lot of paths of the page. The paths aren't protected and contain stuff like sql databases and a lot of other stuff they probablly don't want to be as accessable as it currently is.

Could I get in trouble with law by just accessing the data?
Or is it all there carelessness?

What makes me think I could get in trouble: The content appears to be not directly accessable through any Protocoll supported links, so wihtout the php bug they seemingly have I wouldn't know about the directorys.
And it is probably sensitive data of some users or other stuff, which in generell is treat pretty hot here in germany.

What makes me think its not my problem:

It is just a url without any verification process so how I could even know its not made to be accessed by me, if I had not the technicall knowledge I actually have.
And the hoster of the page is absolutly not even trying to protect this data.
Or even if he is, it is careless anyway, as the database is stored on something like www.domain.tld/conf/sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking generally, it is a double edged sword.

The web site could be held accountable for not taking proper precautions to protect user data.

However, it is usually the burden of the one accessing the data to practice due diligence. That said, you can only plead carelessness up until the point where it was obvious you were not supposed to be there.

pleading carelessness would probably be difficult in the first place seeing as you accessed that portion of the site through a bug to get to a page that is not normally exposed.

Not a lawyer, but my advice is to let it lie.

If they are not practicing even the most basic of user security, the odds are they will never even know you were there.

Answer (score 1):

(Speaking from 5 years old info gotten by searching internet piracy laws)

**In France**, the laws state that unauthorised access is illegal, and more interestingly **maintaining unauthorized access is as much illegal** as getting it.

[Analysis of those laws, in French](http://www.legavox.fr/blog/murielle-cahen/intrusion-dans-systeme-informatique-hacking-314.htm)

I am not aware of the rest of the world's laws, but it seems it is indeed unlawful, as it is trivial to show these data were not intended for your use, making your access unauthorized thus illegal (however well intentioned you might be)

The fact that it is a bug / error that you exploit might be used against you rather than being in your favour, I can't imagine any case where it might be otherwise (since any intrusion is based on bug/error / edge case of security policy)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a lawyer, but speaking in general...

It likely depends on the laws of the country / state / whatever in which you reside, and which you're accessing in. For example, if you do this in a country where it isn't illegal, you'll likely be okay unless they choose to extradite you to the other country. However, if it's illegal in the country where you're accessing the data, you've broken the laws of that country.

Let's propose a scenario:

1. **Country A hasn't made this illegal.**
2. **Country B has made this illegal.**

If you, while being physically in `Country A`, access the data in `Country B`, you've broken the law. If they find out who you are, expect to be arrested on arrival to Country B if they can't extradite you.

The best course, in my opinion, is to simply *inform* them that there's something wrong with their code / permissions without attempting to access it, but even that could get you in trouble depending on the country / state in question.

Either that, or perhaps you should do nothing about it... unless of course, you want to risk jail time.

Comment: `inform them that there's something wrong` The OP is asking if he can legally perform malicious exploration of a spamming website so informing them seems not really in their interest.

Comment: If he's performing malicious exploration, it may not stop them from taking legal action against OP, especially since OP mentioned that what the website is doing isn't unlawful.